# When I set up Hadoop, what permissions are needed on the *underlying* filesystem?

Tags: hadoop, permissions, hdfs, chmod

To be clear, I'm not  asking about setting permissions *in* HDFS, but rather in ext3 or whatever filesystem is being used on the individual datanode machines that HDFS is running on top of.

I know that we set `sudo chown hduser:hadoop /app/hadoop/tmp` , so user `hduser` is the file *owner*, but I'd like to know guidelines for the permissions bits (chmod) on these files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you set the permission to *755* (worse *777*), the files in the underlying filesystem can be read by anyone and surely it's a security issue. A restrictive permission configuration such as *700* makes some sense. This prevents an unauthorized user from simply opening and reading the files from local disk rather that using HDFS API.

In a securely configured cluster as of [Hadopo version 0.22, 0.23 fix](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HDFS-1560), the permissions on datanode data directories (configured by dfs.datanode.data.dir.perm) now default to 0700. Upon startup, the datanode will automatically change the permissions to match the configured value.

In 1.0 the datanode checks for these values to be the same and refuses to start if they are different. You might get exceptions such as the following if the permissions already provided to where the data is stored violates the default permission configured for Hadoop.

> WARN org.apache.hadoop.hdfs.server.datanode.DataNode: Invalid
>   directory in dfs.data.dir: Incorrect permission for
>   /disk1/datanode, expected: rwxr-xr-x, while
>   actual: rwxrwxr-x

I'm quite not sure about what's happening in other versions though. You might want to have a look yourself though.

Answer (score 1):

i don't know if I have correctly understood your question but here's some informations :

**Setting permissions on local filesystem**

Setting permissions is clearly realevant and needed. Indeed, this permissions can enforce your cluster security by preventing non user or even non owner from modify your data. 
Even if you will probably use lower security to set up your cluster, after its intallation you can modify them to have a safe use.

By the way setting your permission to 777 is almost never a good solution, even if it does not imply direct troubles.
[EDIT] : The good behavior is trying to set as less rights as possible. So while Hadoop works, try to set lower access right (best will be 720). But I can not guarantee that hadoop works with other permissions than 755 as it is the default values.

*almost off-topic*

---

**for CHMOD bits**
values are setted by : Owner User Others 
each of these values have 3 capabilities : Read Write Execute (in this order)
Since theses capabilities can be setted to true(1) or false(0) it result on an octal value given by the binary values.

For instance
    for Owner you want all right, so rwx => 111 = 4 + 2 + 1 = 7
    for User only read and execute, r-x => 101 = 4+0+1 = 5
    and same for others, r-x => 101 = 4+0+1 = 5

So you have to do a  chmod 755 file

**for hdfs rights on host filesystem**

Hadoop is very sensitive to files and directories access rights on its file system. So if you have not setted them correctly it can throw exception and even prevent namenode or datanodes from starting.
As far as i know some parts of your files have to be own by hadoop:hadoop or hdfs:hadoop and some others by mapred:hadoop (according to your hdfs and mapred users and groups).

---

Comment: Thanks, yes, I am familiar with chmod, and asking about guidelines for setting permissions on the  underlying filesystem (not HDFS, but rather the one in which HDFS stored its files). I understand that hduser is the relevant owner and that  it is important to restrict permissions to the minimum necessary -- but what settings should I choose? Of course not 777 -- Is 755 correct? Or are there some more complex guidelines?

Comment: ow, so I misunderstood ^^ 
For your access settings, the less rights is the best. So set files to read/write only for users who need them.
For data : 7 for owner 2 for user (only read) and 0 for other seems to be the best behavior. But 755 is also ok (that's the configuration i use atm even if I'll try to set them to 720 as much as possible)